# Lack of user-defined table types for passing data between stored procedures in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

So I know there's already similar questions on this, but most of them are very old, or they have non-answers, like "why would you even want to do this?", or "table types aren't performant and we don't want them here", or even "you need to rethink your whole approach".

So what I would ideally want to do is to declare a user-defined table type like this:

```
CREATE TYPE my_table AS TABLE (
    a int,
    b date);
```

Then use this in a procedure as a parameter, like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure (
    my_table_parameter my_table)
```

Then be able to do stuff like this:

```
INSERT INTO
    my_temp_table
SELECT
    m.a,
    m.b,
    o.useful_data
FROM
    my_table m
    INNER JOIN my_schema.my_other_table o ON o.a = m.a;
```

This is for a billing system, let's make it a mobile phone billing system (it isn't but it's similar enough to work). Here's several ways I might call my procedure:

- I sometimes want to call my procedure for one row, to create an adhoc bill for one customer. I want to do this while they are on the phone and get them an immediate result. Maybe I just fixed something wrong with their bill, and they're angry!
- I sometimes want to bill everyone who's due a bill on a specific date. Maybe this is their preferred billing date, and they're on a monthly billing cycle?
- I sometimes want to bill in bulk, but my data comes from a CSV file. Maybe this is a custom billing run that I have no way of understanding the motivation for?
- Maybe I want to final bill customers who recently left?
- Sometimes I might need to rebill customers because a mistake was made. Maybe a tariff rate was uploaded incorrectly, and everyone on that tariff needs their bill regenerating?

I want to split my code up into modules, it's easier to work like this, and it allows a large degree of reusability. So what I don't want to do is to write n billing systems, where each one handles one of the use cases above. I want a generic billing engine that is a stored procedure, uses set-based queries where possible, and works just about as well for one customer as it does for 1,000,000. If anything I want it optimised for lots of customers, as long as it only takes a few seconds to run for one customer.

If I had SQL Server I would create a user-defined table type, and this would contain a list of customers, the date they need billing to, and maybe anything else that would be useful. But let's just leave it at the simplest case possible, an `integer` representing a customer and a `date` to say what date I want to bill them up to, like my example above.

I've spent some days now looking at the options available in PostgreSQL, and these are the conclusions I have reached. I would be extremely grateful for any help with this, correcting my incorrect assumptions, or telling me of another way I have overlooked.

### Process-Keyed Table

Create a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_list (
    process_key int,
    customer_id int,
    bill_to_date date);
```

When I want to call my billing system I get a unique key (probably from a sequence), load up the rows with my list of customers/ dates to bill them to, and add the unique key to every row. Now I can simply pass the unique key to my billing engine, and it can scoop up the data at the other side.

This seems the most optional way to proceed, but it's clunky, like something I would have done in SQL Server 20 years ago, when there weren't better options, it's prone to leaving data lying around, and it doesn't seem like it would be optimal, as the data will have to be squirted to physical storage, and read back into memory.

### Use a Temporary Table

So I'm thinking that I create a temporary table, call it `customer_temp`, and make it `ON COMMIT DROP`. When I call my stored procedure to bill customers it picks the data out of the temporary table, does what it needs to do, and then when it ends the table is vacuumed away.

But this doesn't work if I call the billing engine more than once at a time. So I need to give my temporary tables unique names, and also pass this name into my billing engine, which has to use some vile dynamic SQL to get the data into some usable area (probably another temporary table?).

### Use a TYPE

When I first saw this I thought I had the answer, but it turns out to not work for multidimensional arrays (or I'm doing something wrong). I quickly learned that for a single dimensional array I could get this working by just pretending that a PostgreSQL `TYPE` was a user defined table type. But it obviously isn't.

So passing in an array of integers, e.g. `customer_list int[];` works fine, and I can use the `ARRAY` command to populate that array from a query, and then it's easy to access it with `=ANY(customer_list)` at the other side. It's not ideal, and I bet it's awful for large data sets, but it's neat.

However, it doesn't work for multidimensional arrays, the `ARRAY` command can't cope with a query that has more than one column in it, and the other side becomes more awkward, needing an `UNNEST` command to unpack the data into a format where it's usable.

I defined my type like this:

```
CREATE TYPE customer_list (
    customer_id int,
    bill_to_date date);
```

...and then used it in my procedure parameter list as `customer_list[]`, which seems to work, but I have no nice way to populate this structure from the calling procedure.

I feel I'm missing something here, as I never got it to work properly as a prototype, but I also feel this is a potential dead end anyway, as it won't cope with large numbers of rows in a performant way, and this isn't what arrays are meant for. The first thing I do with the array at the other side, is unpack it back into a table again, which seems counterintuitive.

### Ref Cursors

I read that you can use `REF CURSOR`s, but I'm not quite sure how this works. It seems that you open a cursor in one procedure, and then pass a handle to it to another procedure. It doesn't seem like this is going to be set-based, but I could be wrong, and I just haven't found a way to convert a cursor back into a table again?

### Write Everything as One Massive Procedure

I'm not ruling this out, as PostgreSQL seems to be leading me this way. If I write one enormous billing engine that copes with every eventuality, then my only issue will be when this is called using an externally provided list. Every other issue can be solved by just not having to pass data between procedures.

I can probably cope with this by loading the data into a batch table, and feeding this in as one of the options. It's awful, and it's like going back to the 1990s, but if this is what PostgreSQL wants me to do, then so be it.

### Final Thoughts

I'm sure I'm going to be asked for code examples, which I will happily provide, but I avoided because this post is already uber-long, and what I'm trying to achieve is actually quite simple I feel.

Having typed all of this out, I'm still feeling that there must be a way of working around the "temporary table names must be unique", as this would work nicely if I found a way to let it be called in a multithreaded way.

---

Okay, taking the bits I was missing I came up with this, which seems to work:

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS bill_list AS (
    customer_id int,
    bill_date date);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS billing.pending_bill (
    customer_id int,
    bill_date date);
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS billing.customer (
    customer_id int,
    billed boolean,
    last_billed date);

INSERT INTO billing.customer
VALUES 
(1, false, NULL::date),
(2, false, NULL::date),
(3, false, NULL::date);

INSERT INTO billing.pending_bill
VALUES 
(1, '20210108'::date),
(2, '20210105'::date),
(3, '20210104'::date);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE billing.bill_customer_list (
    pending bill_list[])
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        billing.customer c
    SET
        billed = true,
        last_billed = p.bill_date
    FROM
        UNNEST(pending) p
    WHERE
        p.customer_id = c.customer_id;
END;
$$

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE billing.test ()
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS
$$
DECLARE pending bill_list[];
BEGIN
    pending := ARRAY(SELECT p FROM billing.pending_bill p);    
    CALL billing.bill_customer_list (pending);
END;
$$
```

Comment: Yes we need to see actual working code examples. For one `DECLARE my_procedure PROCEDURE (my_table_parameter my_table)` does not work in Postgres. Also pretty sure `CREATE TYPE` would work.  Basically this question over long and lacking in the clarity a working example would provide.

Comment: How is using an array of a custom type with `unnest` different than using a `select .. from table_variable`?

Comment: I have been working with Oracle for 25 years and with Postgres for over 15 years and I never missed "table types". In fact I only discovered a couple of years ago that such a thing exists. So we don't agree that this is a feature "most definitely" lacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your select in the procedure returns multiple columns. But you want to create an array of a custom type. So your SELECT list needs to return the type, not `*`.

You don't need the `bill_list` type either, as every table has a corresponding type and you can simply pass an array of the table's type.

So you can use the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE bill_customer_list (
    pending pending_bill[])
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        customer c
    SET
        billed = true
    FROM unnest(pending) p --<< treat the array as a table
    WHERE
        p.customer_id = c.customer_id;
END;
$$
;

CREATE PROCEDURE test ()
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS
$$
DECLARE 
  pending pending_bill[];
BEGIN
    pending := ARRAY(SELECT p FROM pending_bill p);    
    CALL bill_customer_list (pending);
END;
$$
;
```

The `select p` returns a record (of the same type as the table) as a single column in the result.

The `:=` is the [assignment operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) in PL/pgSQL and typically [much faster](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/assignment-performance/) than a `SELECT .. INTO variable`. Although in this case the performance difference wouldn't matter much I guess.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=10c2c9a910febd2d33902ee950270dc0)

---

If you do want to keep the extra type bill_list around because it e.g. contains less columns than `pending_bill` you need to select only those columns that match the type's column and create a [record](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) by enclosing them in parentheses. `(a,b)` is a single column with an anonymous record type (and two fields). `a,b` are two distinct columns

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test ()
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS
$$
DECLARE 
  pending bill_list[];
BEGIN
    pending := ARRAY(SELECT (id, customer_id) FROM pending_bill p);    
    CALL bill_customer_list (pending);
END;
$$
;
```

---

You should also note that `DECLARE` starts a **block** in PL/pgSQL where multiple variables can be defined. There is no need to write one `DECLARE` for each variable (your formatting of the DECLARE block let's me think that you assumed you need one DECLARE per variable as is the case in T-SQL)

Comment: Okay, that's the bit I was missing, I've never seen that `:=` syntax used before. I'm also failing to understand how this works. What does the `SELECT p` bit do? I know you explained this in your answer, but I'm not getting it for some reason (decades of SQL Server to blame I guess). Finally, what if my query wasn't as simple as the one in my rather made up example, so I needed to select multiple columns from a series of tables to put together the billing list? Would I have to put it into the right format (customer_id and bill_date) somewhere, to use the same method?

Comment: The "unnest = table" bit is golden, and I understand how that works now, so thanks for that! :)

Comment: `select p` selects a "record" column - essentially an instance of the record type as a single column. The `select ... into` would work as well, but typically using the [assignment operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) is faster in PL/pgSQL I have added an example if you want a subset of the columns in the record.