Equivalent sql server USER DEFINED TABLE TYPE in postgreSql?
It is clear that you can not use NOT NULL in a TYPE in postgreSql, whereas you can use it in a DOMAIN. However I do not believe DOMAIN is the correct application of what I have working in SQL Server but in PostgreSql ? What is the correct usage equivalent in PostgreSQL?
SQL SERVER:
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Purchase_Type] AS TABLE(
[Month] [char](9) NOT NULL,
[Value] [int] NOT NULL,
[Buy] [int] NULL,
[Sell] [int] NULL
)

The use case is to receive a dataTable as parameter to a SQL procedure to insert into the Purchase table:
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertPurchase]
@purchaseTable Purchase_Type readonly

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Insert into [dbo].Purchase select * from @purchaseTable


Just skip the constraints and use CREATE TYPE? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66108122/lack-of-user-defined-table-types-for-passing-data-between-stored-procedures-in-p

The type maps to a table in the database, so I would prefer it to have the same constraints as the table

"I do not believe DOMAIN is the correct application of what I have working in SQL Server" - we do not know what your application and use case is for what you have working in SQL Server, so we can't tell what is correct.

Thanks @Bergi, I added to the question.

Domain is for scalar types from what i understand of postgre docs, something like use defined type (non table) in sql server

@Allstar I dunno why you think it's wrong to pass a domain value to a procedure/function. Although I also don't understand why you have a procedure for inserting into a table in the first place, does the procedure do anything else than that?

You probably could have your procedure simply accept a Purchase row, without creating any separate user-defined type. Every table implicitly declares its row type already. If you want to do validation, that either happens implicitly during the insert anyway (table constraints) or you could do manual checks inside the procedure.

A procedure can accept several input parameters. Creating a specific composite data type for that is unnecessarily complicated.

@Bergi, your last comment above  made me realize why I would  want constraint NOT NULL in my TYPE.. since the insert into table will do the constraint check anyway, I do not need the constraint in the TYPE thus. And then I can just use CREATE TYPE

@Allstar If you're not using it for anything else, you can use the target table for the parameter type directly and skip the type thing completely.

I can just literally use the table name as the parameter type?

Yes. There's an online demo in my answer where you can see that working just fine.

If [dbo].[Purchase_Type] is just supposed to follow the structure of [dbo].Purchase, you can use the table you're targetting as the type you want, directly: demo at db<>fiddle
CREATE TABLE "dbo".Purchase (
    "Month" character(9) NOT NULL,
    "Value" int NOT NULL,
    "Buy" int NULL,
    "Sell" int NULL );

And then you can pass the row into the procedure and unpack it in your insert statement:
CREATE PROCEDURE "dbo"."InsertPurchase"
(purchaseTable IN "dbo".Purchase)--readonly parameter uses the table as type
AS $p$ BEGIN
 insert into "dbo"."Purchase" select purchaseTable.*;
END $p$ language plpgsql;

CALL "dbo"."InsertPurchase"( ('June',1,null,1) );

SELECT * FROM "dbo"."Purchase";




Month
Value
Buy
Sell




June
1
null
1



To handle multiple rows, you can make that an array and unnest() it:
CREATE PROCEDURE "dbo"."InsertPurchase"
(purchaseTable IN "dbo"."Purchase"[]) language SQL AS 
$p$ insert into "dbo"."Purchase" select r.* from unnest(purchaseTable) r $p$;

CALL "dbo"."InsertPurchase"(array[ ('July',1,null,1)
                                  ,('August',2,2,null)
                                 ]::"dbo"."Purchase"[]);

Or you can also pass a name of a table from which you want this procedure to get the rows and insert into the target, using dynamic sql. You can't hold an actual table in a variable and pass that in, like you would in SQL Server.

The parameter for the procedure InsertPurchase is a dataTable / Purchase table

Having two CREATE TABLE statements is weird. Did you mean to CREATE TYPE first, then create a table of that type? Though usually you'd just create a single table only, then refer to the type which gets implicitly created for it in the procedure

@Allstar Then the parameter would have to be an array of "dbo"."Purchase_Type", or a name of a table holding the rows: demo - that's because there's no TVP in PostgreSQL.

@Bergi It does look and feel weird. I did mean to create type but the whole problem here is that it wouldn't allow you to set up the constraints. As proposed in the comments, you'd probably have to first create a domain over character to disallow null value, and then use that for your first field of the custom type, then repeat the process for the rest of the fields. My suggestion is a dummy table can serve the exact same purpose and later you can CREATE TABLE ...(LIKE...) using that, similar to how you'd CREATE TABLE... OF TYPE....

Hm yeah but this is simpler and creates no unnecessary extra table. (On this you could still create a domain to prevent creating a row of the type, not only to prevent insertion into the table).

@Bergi You're right. I got a bit too focused on setting up the type and showing how you can use a table instead, but neither is necessary if there's already a table this is supposed to feed, that can be used to define that parameter type. Showing that intermediate step with the table/type thing makes little sense in the absence of anything else on the topic of the type+domain vs table, so I removed that completely when adding the multiple row handling. Thanks for pointing that out
